# How to add picture credits to the query?

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-api

I have an example query of

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?image WHERE {
  ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?person wdt:P18 ?image.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "de". }

}
```

And I want to use a credit below the picture as in

Foto: [Martina Nolte](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benutzer:Martina_Nolte) Lizenz: [Creative Commons by-sa 3.0 de](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/de/legalcode) / [Kurz](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/de/)

How do I add columns for each part, ie

```
name of photographer - link to profile - license - short version of license
```

I tried too much to list.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get those credits data from Wikidata Query at the moment, but there is a tool on wmflabs.org that offers just that: http://tools.wmflabs.org/magnus-toolserver/commonsapi.php

So P18 gives you the file name on Commons, then you just have to request: http://tools.wmflabs.org/magnus-toolserver/commonsapi.php?image=Eduardo%20Frei%20Chiledebate.jpg

It respond in XML only unfortunately.